# On sale products shows duplicated

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I create a new page named SALE , to only show the on sale products
Im using the following shortcode
[sale_products per_page="9" columns="4"]

but I dont know why it duplicates the product on the footer area 
you can see it here https://prueba.soygorrion.com.ar/sale/

Any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try with default theme .    however i could not see any duplicate on your link.  your question dosen't follow the rule.

Comment: thank you but Im seeing the product duplicated anyway.

Comment: try this :
[products on_sale="true" limit="10" orderby="title" order="ASC"]

Comment: thank you, but im seeing the product duplicate https://prueba.soygorrion.com.ar/sale/